# Loading images in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Well, I'm working on `tkinter` and I'd like to load an image to my program and then I got a syntax error.

This is my code:

```
app = Tk()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:\Users\radwan\Desktop\projets\Bienvenue.jpg")                                                                               
label_photo = Label(app,image=photo)                                                                                                         
label_photo.pack(side=BOTTOM)                                                                                                                                               
app.mainloop()
```

and this is the terminal message:

```
> File "C:\Users\radwan\Desktop\projets\app.py", line 75
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:\Users\radwan\Desktop\projets\Bienvenue.jpg")
                             ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

you can not use single backslash in filename like "C:\Users\radwan\Desktop\projets\Bienvenue.jpg", but double "C:\\Users\\radwan\\Desktop\\projets\\Bienvenue.jpg"

Comment: sorry but the label_image doesn't appear on my screen, i don't know why?!

Comment: The PhotoImage class can read only GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:

Comment: You need Pillow module for jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is code with PIL

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\radwan\\Desktop\\projets\\Bienvenue.jpg")
label_photo = Label(root,image=photo)
label_photo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```